# Spark S3 SocketTimeoutException

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

My spark application encounters a socket timeout exception trying to pull down an S3 file. It works fine as a Java 'main' application in my IDE but errors out like this when started with the ./spark-submit script in stand-alone mode on the local machine.

```
15/05/06 14:02:33 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times;
aborting job 

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most 
recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): 

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

In the stand-alone mode, is this code running in the Driver / Worker? Are there any logs I should be looking into?

Thanks,
Ranjit